# python eval ignoring local, and looking for a global

Tags: python, global-variables, eval, local-variables

When I run this code in a new Python 3.4.1 shell window:

```
>>> def golf(c):
 a,d=[],{"U":"a.append(int(x[5]))","O":'a.pop() if a else 0',"E":'a[-1]'}
 return sum(eval(d[x[1]])or 0 for x in c)or 0

>>> golf(("PUSH 3", "POP", "POP", "PUSH 4", "PEEK", "PUSH 9", "PUSH 0", "PEEK", "POP", "PUSH 1", "PEEK"))
```

I get this error even though I declare ***a*** in the second line -- a,d=[],{.....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    golf(("PUSH 3", "POP", "POP", "PUSH 4", "PEEK", "PUSH 9", "PUSH 0", "PEEK", "POP", "PUSH 1", "PEEK"))
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 3, in golf
    return sum(eval(d[x[1]])or 0 for x in c)or 0
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 3, in <genexpr>
    return sum(eval(d[x[1]])or 0 for x in c)or 0
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

(NOTE: If I declare ***a*** in the shell as an empty array, it updates with each run of ***golf()*** instead of being re-declared as empty in the function.)

If that wasn't weird enough, I can 'fix' the problem by taking the ***eval()*** out of the generator. Like this:

```
def golf(c):
 a,d=[],{"U":"a.append(int(x[5]))","O":'a.pop() if a else 0',"E":'a[-1]'}
 for x in c:
  print(eval(d[x[1]])or 0)
 return []
```

Even though ***a*** is still undefined (in the shell window), I get:

```
0
3
0
0
4
0
0
0
0
0
1
[]
```

Why is ***eval()*** ignoring my local ***a***?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python idiom [Default Parameter Values](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#id35):

```
def good_append(new_item, a_list=None):
    if a_list is None:
        a_list = []
    a_list.append(new_item)
    return a_list
```